# Is there a way to group methods/properties in the outline view of Aptana IDE

Tags: xcode, eclipse, ide, aptana, outline-view

I've looked everywhere for a feature like this. I use the Aptana IDE (which is based on Eclipse) for my php development, and I use the outline feature a lot.

I enjoy xcode's 'pragma mark' feature, which lets you group sections of your source code together in the outline view for quick reference. (Described here: http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2006/09/tip-pragma-mark-organizing-your-source.html)

Is there anything like this for Aptana/Eclipse?

Comment: I would like this also, so useful!

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have found is to do one of these two things:

Create a dummy constant, or create a dummy function.  Both will create entries in the outline.  See screenshot.  Personally, I think I like the constant better, because its icon in the outline makes it clear it isn't really a function.

[image]